# Odd SQLAlchemy behaviour

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application that uploads files to amazon s3 in a celery process. I user sqlalchemy for database access.

I have a db file containing my scoped session definition as shown below

```
sess = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db_session = scoped_session(sess)
```

This db module is imported by the views as well as the celery process. When I upload a file and store it to the database in the view code, an attempt to query the database for the newly added object from the celery process returns an empty set. This is regardless of the fact that a commit was carried out after the insert in the view code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting... Maybe you have threads/processes messing up with the *actual* order the data is inserted? (From http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#thread-local-scope, a single Session is maintained for all who call upon the scoped_session registry, but only within the scope of a single thread)?

Comment: So... fist you use a view to upload a file, you save it in the db and then you spawn the celery process, which queries the db and gets an empty set, is that right? Could you add the chunk of code in your view/celery process that do that?

Comment: Try to debug this with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` (runs the task synchronously in the same process). If it works, then you are probably missing some initialization in your DB engine/session that should take place in the celery worker process.

Comment: this sounds like a [transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) issue.  if the view code hasn't committed the transaction, or if the Celery process has already begun a transaction before the view code committed, then the row might not be visible.